Is it possible to have a different HDR lighting setup in each view layer?
Is it possible to have a different HDR lighting setup in each view layer?
It seems to be a global setting.
I am using Blender 4.2 with Cycles

To be exact, it's a Scene-level data. View Layers can be summarized as a tool to have different sets of collections visibilities within a Scene. Hence here it would probably be better to use Scenes instead of View Layers.

Create a custom property with the same name in each view layer, set one property to 1, other (in second view layer) to 0:

Set up world shader like this, set hdris instead RGB nodes

Add driver to mix factor. Type - context property, Context - Active View Layer, Path - ["prop"]. Where prop - is the custom property name

